# Use JSON returned by Azure Logic App HTTP connector

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I created a HTTP

It's `Body` property returns a JSON hash:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 123456,
        "fullname": "Last, First",
        "code": null,
        "status": 1,
        "self": "https://api.xxx.com/rest/v1.0/xxx/123456",
        "limits": null,
        "accumulated": null,
        "custom_data_field": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
          },
          {
            "id": 6,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
          }
        ],
        "access_groups": []
      }
    ],
    "meta": {
      "previous": null,
      "total": 1,
      "per_page": 50,
      "next": "https://api.xxx.com/rest/v1.0/xxx?page%5Bnumber%5D=2"
    }
}
```

I would like to loop each items in the `data` element.

What is the next step?  `Initialize variable`?  `Append to an array variable`?  In either case, what's the syntax to get each element's (e.g. `data.fullname`) value?

Comment: Hi craig, may I know if the solution helps your problem ? If still have any problem or it doesn't meet your requirements, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As you described in your question, if you want to loop the items in the `data` element, you just need to use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the whole json string. Such as below screenshot(in screenshot I initialize a variable named "source" which store your json string to simulate your situation)
[image]

In "Parse JSON" action, please click "**Use sample payload to generate schema**" button and input your json string, it will generate the schema automatically.

Then add a "[For each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop)" loop and use the "data" from "Parse JSON" as the element of the loop.
[image]

In the "For each", you can use any element in the data as shown in the screenshot above.